# Independent project index for each customer

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In my database, I have different customers with an id (1001, 1002, ...) and want to add projects to each customer (1:n-relation). I want the id of the project to increment independently for each customer, so that I have projects 101, 102, ... for customer 1001 and different projects 101, 102, ... for customer 1002 (with same project-id). How can I achieve this?

I want to combine the customer and project ids, so that I get something like this to uniquely identify the projects:

- 1001.101 -> Project A
- 1001.102 -> Project B
- ...
- 1002.101 -> Project C
- 1002.102 -> Project D
- ...

Right now, the id for the project is incrementing globally:

```
CREATE TABLE customer 
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    company_name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE project 
(
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,
    id serial,
    project_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customer (id),
    PRIMARY KEY(customer_id, id)
);

SELECT setval('customer_id_seq', 1000);
SELECT setval('project_id_seq', 100);
```

Comment: Don't persist that in the database. Calculate the project number on the fly using a window function when you query the table.

Answer (score 1):

As Laurenz Albe pointed out, the solution is to create a window function like this:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    100 + (
        RANK() OVER (
        PARTITION BY customer_id
        ORDER BY id
        )
    )
    project_id
FROM
    project;
```